# performing one hot encoding with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am making the following data frame in Pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([20,"admin","France",
                             25,"worker","Italy",
                             45,"admin","Norway",
                             30,"sec","EEUU",
                             25,"law",np.NaN,
                             30,"sec","France"]

            ).reshape(6,3))
df.columns=["age","job","country"]
```

and I want to perform one hot encoding, but without using the get_dummies feature, instead I want to use OneHotEncoder. So I made the following code:

```
def oneHotEncoding(df):
    ohe=preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(dtype=np.int,sparse=True,handle_unknown="ignore")
    values=pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(df[["country"]]).toarray())
    df=pd.concat([df,values],axis=1)
    df=df.drop(["country"],1)
    print(df)
```

The problem is when I get the results, I get something like:

```
   age  job    0  1  2  3  4
0   20  admin  0  1  0  0  0
1   25  worker 0  0  1  0  0
2   45  admin  0  0  0  1  0
3   30  sec    1  0  0  0  0
4   25  law    0  0  0  0  1
5   30  sec    0  1  0  0  0
```

I would like that in the columns of the results appears something like country_france, country_italy and so on, I have tried the following code:

```
values=pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(df[["country"]]).toarray(),columns=["country_"+str(int(i)) for i in range(df.shape[1])])
```

but it didn´t give me the correct results.

Also, the nan value is still considered like a country and it should be like only 0.

How can I fix those issues? I have tested different possibilities that I found here and nothing helps me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using `OneHotEncoder`, your issue is that your sparse matrix has no column data, the attributes are actually stored on `ohe` in your example.

After you use `fit_transform`, you can access the categories from the `categories_` attribute on the `OneHotEncoder`

---

```
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(dtype=np.int,sparse=True,handle_unknown="ignore")

data = ohe.fit_transform(df[['country']])

values = pd.DataFrame(data.A, columns='country_' + ohe.categories_[0])
```

```
   country_EEUU  country_France  country_Italy  country_Norway  country_nan
0             0               1              0               0            0
1             0               0              1               0            0
2             0               0              0               1            0
3             1               0              0               0            0
4             0               0              0               0            1
5             0               1              0               0            0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @user3483203 I have one silly question, when you retrieve the sparse matrix, how did you know that the variable was A? I mean in data.A, I have looked in different manuals and was not able to find that, is it a Python convention like A=Array? Thank you

Comment: It's just a shorthand for converting a sparse matrix to an array, to get a 1 dimensional array, shorthand is `A1`

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` we have the `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['country'])
Out[429]: 
  age     job     ...       country_Norway  country_nan
0  20   admin     ...                    0            0
1  25  worker     ...                    0            0
2  45   admin     ...                    1            0
3  30     sec     ...                    0            0
4  25     law     ...                    0            1
5  30     sec     ...                    0            0
[6 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: thanks @WeNYoBen, but for practice reasons I wanted to know how it can be made with OneHotEncoder